# How do I convert string to a date in rethinkdb using python?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

My rethinkdb stores data in the following format.

```
data = [{
      'appName': "app1",
      'startTime': "Mon, 14 Feb 2017 05:10:00 GMT",
      'endTime': "Mon, 14 Feb 2017 05:15:00 GMT",
      'status': "SUCCESS"
    },
    {
      'appName': "app1",
      'startTime': "Mon, 13 Feb 2017 05:10:00 GMT",
      'endTime': "Mon, 13 Feb 2017 05:15:00 GMT",
      'status': "FAILED"
    },
    {
      'appName': "app2",
      'startTime': "Mon, 13 Feb 2017 05:10:00 GMT",
      'endTime': "Mon, 13 Feb 2017 05:15:00 GMT",
      'status': "RUNNING"
    }]
```

I need to fetch the latest information for all apps.

```
r.table('apps').group('appName').max('startTime').run()
```

But since my startTime is stored as a string, I can not do a max operation.

I tried updating the values in the table as follows,

```
r.table('apps').update({'startTimeDate': pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome').localize(datetime.strptime(r.row['startTime'], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'))}).run()
```

I receive an error:

> TypeError: must be string, not Bracket

How do I persist startTime and endTime as date in rethinkdb from string?

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB only supports dates formatted as ISO8601 or as a number of seconds since the UNIX epoch.

Your `update` query has the right idea, but it tries to use python functions inside the `update`, where `row['startTime']` is a query fragment and not a string.

Something like this might work instead:

```
for app in r.table('apps').run():
  date = (pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome')
              .localize(datetime.strptime(app['startTime'],
                                          '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'))
  (r.table('apps')
    .get(app['id'])
    .update({'startTimeDate': date},
            durability='soft')
  ).run()
r.table('apps').sync()
```